# Ruby Net::HTTP.start calling a URL twice

Tags: ruby, net-http

I am trying to hit a URL in Ruby with the following code:

```
begin
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :read_timeout=>5) do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
    @response = http.request request
    @responsecode = @response.code.to_i
  end
rescue Exception => e
  ::NewRelic::Agent.notice_error(e)
end
```

The problem I am having is that the URL is hit twice.I don't know why is this happening.Any help is appreciated.If I remove the :read_timeout, it works fine.

EDIT:
The problem I found is if service takes longer than read_timeout to respond, it is hit again.

Comment: Why do you think that it hit's twice?

Comment: Its a service whose response I captured.